# Getting Azure AD users is taking way to much time! How to reduce the time?

Tags: c#, list, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am getting Azure AD users into a list to be used in a dropdown, but it takes about at least 8/9 seconds to do the call... I know this can probably be reduced... So I will place my code here, hoping that someone can give me a better idea of how to change the code to a better one.

```
 public async Task<List<Microsoft.Graph.User>> getAzureUsers()
        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("***")
                .WithTenantId("***")
                .WithClientSecret("***")
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            List<Microsoft.Graph.User> utilizadores = new List<Microsoft.Graph.User>();
            

            var user = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Select(p => new {
                    p.DisplayName,
                    p.UserPrincipalName,
                    p.Id
                })
                .GetAsync();

            utilizadores.AddRange(user.CurrentPage);

            while (user.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                user = await user.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                utilizadores.AddRange(user.CurrentPage);
            }

            return utilizadores;
        }
```

```
 public async Task<ViewModelColaboradores> GetVM()
        {
            bool colExist = false;

            List<Microsoft.Graph.User> utilizadores = new List<Microsoft.Graph.User>();
            List<UserAD> nomes = new List<UserAD>();
            utilizadores = await getAzureUsers();

            ViewModelColaboradores vm = new ViewModelColaboradores();
            foreach (var n in utilizadores)
            {
                foreach (var col in _context.RH_Colaboradores)
                {
                    if (n.DisplayName == col.Nome)
                    {
                        colExist = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!colExist)
                {

                    nomes.Add(new UserAD { DisplayName = n.DisplayName, Id = n.Id, Email = n.UserPrincipalName });
                }
                colExist = false;
            }
            vm.usersAd = nomes;

            return vm;
        }
```

and then I just call GETVM to get the viewmodel with the users inside. Any ideas?

Comment: how many users are we talking about? Yes, pulling them all into a list could be slow if there are a large number. And it will be hard for users to scroll through the dropdown list anyway. Why not implement an auto-complete style functionality instead (which is what microsoft themselves do in most of their tools when you have to select a username) where the user starts tying the name or ID of the person they want, and once they entered 2 or 3 characters it starts searching for matching records. Then you only need to return a few records at once.

Comment: about 300 right now... They also dont need to scroll, im using a chosen dropdown, where they can just type the name or part of it and the names with that content will appear... 

The only reason im doing this is because i was asked to.. I dont know if i can do it that way but i will see because it seems like a good idea.. Can you give me a link so that i can get the info? 

Still, if you have any approach that can make what im doing in a better way i will still be happy..so i can go to my "client" and show what ive implemented in the best way possible, but show talk about your idea.

Comment: One more thing, how it will autofill without having the users in a list? how does he know that there is something to complete without pulling them first?

Comment: "how it will autofill without having the users in a list"...because it only makes a call to the Graph API _after_ the user starts typing in the field. At that point it launches a search query (rather than just a "give me all the records" query, using the data the user typed in order to filter on the API side. Therefore, the results you get back from the API are much reduced. Something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583153/microsoft-graph-ad-users-or-people-api-to-search-all-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pagination` to improve the performance.

You can have a **search-based dropdown(non-paginated)** or **scroll based dropdown (paginated - that fetches new items on scrolling down and fetches scroll up results from cache)**.

**C# sample code:**

```
public async Task<AzureUserDto> GetUsersPage(int pageSize, string skipToken)
{
    var filterString = $"startswith(givenName, '{firstName}')";

    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
    {
        new QueryOption("$top", pageSize)
    };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(skipToken))
    {
        queryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$skiptoken", skipToken));
    }

    var azureUsers = await GraphServiceClient.Users
            .Request(queryOptions)
            .Filter(filterString)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Id,
                x.DisplayName,
                x.GivenName,
                x.Surname,
                x.UserPrincipalName,
                x.AccountEnabled,
                x.Identities,
                x.BusinessPhones,
                x.JobTitle,
                x.MobilePhone,
                x.OfficeLocation,
                x.PreferredLanguage,
                x.Mail
            })
            .GetAsync();

    // Get SkipToken, if exists
    var skipToken = azureUsers
        .NextPageRequest?
        .QueryOptions?
        .FirstOrDefault(
            x => string.Equals("$skiptoken", x.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))?
        .Value;

    var azureUserDto = new AzureUserDto
    {
        // Map the azureUsers to AzureUsersDto or something similar and return
        // don't forget to include the SkipToken
    };

    return azureUsers;
}
```

For more details on how to implement the latter method, you can visit [Paging Microsoft Graph data in your app](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging) and [Microsoft Graph API: C# / Filtering / Pagination.](https://iqunlock.com/microsoft-graph-api-c-sharp/)

Comment: Can you give me an example of usage? i dont understand what i got to do

Comment: I never said that. I just want some example/clear explanation if possible from what they say there... Before i wrote this question i already had read the linked page. I simply did not understand what they do there

Comment: And as far as i understood i am already getting paginated users....

Comment: Pls check my updated response with C3 code and added new link for tutorial.